# Assigning an animation to a sprite node in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation, skspritenode

I am eager to develop an animation for my playable character in my game the problem is I do not know how to Animate a sprite node so that the playable character loops through a set of images to simulate an animation.I want to make my playable sprite node player to animate through a set of images so that it appears as if it is running . Help would be great thanks !

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Have you read the chapter "Working with Texture Objects" in the SpriteKit Programming Guide? There's an example of exactly this.